# matching query does not exist - Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a registration page. I extended django's User model to add additional fields. I have two forms connected with OnetoOnefield. I am getting this error.

```
DoesNotExist at /register/
Influencer matching query does not exist.
```

I think what I am doing wrong is creating User and Influencer model at the same time.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Influencer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ig_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}"


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_influencer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Influencer.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_influencer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.influencer.save()
```

My forms.py file:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class InfluencerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Influencer
        fields = ('bio', 'ig_url')
```

My views.py file:

```
def register(request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = InfluencerProfileForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile = Influencer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile_form = InfluencerProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Comment: It means there is no `Influencer` for the given `request.user`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in two places. One, you have a signal which creates `Influencer` instance where you al. Second, you are assuming you will have a `Influencer` instance  before creating one. You can remove the signals and try with the following code:

```
def register(request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = InfluencerProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            try:
                profile_form = InfluencerProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.influencer)  # due to OneToOne relation, it will work
            except:
               pass
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Comment: I made the changes and I get the error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register/
User has no influencer.

Comment: That means you do not have an Influencer object for that user. You need to create it manually, or add a try catch. I have updated the answer

Comment: I wanted to have Influencer object created when the form is submitted. Should I make changes to the signal? @ruddra

Comment: It appears for the particular user you are testing with does not have a Influencer object. So, with this implementation, it will create a new influencer object for that user when the form is submitted. But if you create a new user, then it will automatically create the influencer instance with that user.

Comment: Yeah creating new user and its influencer instance is what I am trying to do. Can you suggest changes to my original code? I thought the signal will create the influencer object for the User. Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: I would not recommend signals, as you already have the form. If you do not use form when creating a User and Influencer, then your first signal should be sufficient. Second signal `save_influencer` is redundant and you should remove it.